# Servidor en Ubuntu se desconecta esporádicamente

Tags: ubuntu, servidor

Monté un servidor web en Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, que será usado de forma interna en la empresa para el envío de correos automáticos mediante scripts de php, y otras web apps en php y angular que funcionarán allí, el servidor funciona perfecto, los servidores (me refiero a apache, glassfish, node) siguen encendidos todo el tiempo, pero por alguna razón pierde la conexión a la red de un momento a otro, a veces vuelve, pero la mayoría de las veces debo reiniciar el servicio de la tarjeta de red para que se reestablezca, lo extraño es que al hacer ping desde otro equipo funciona y viceversa, pero ya no salen los mensajes ni deja acceder a los proyectos que están corriendo en el servidor.  ¿porque pasa esto, como lo soluciono?.  obviamente debe permanecer accesible todo el tiempo.

Comment: Revisa las bitácoras de tu servidor. La verdad es que si no es un problema reproducible y su aparición es aleatoria, no podemos ayudarte. La pregunta es muy amplia para el sitio.

Comment: Estas seguro que es la misma máquina que te contesta el ping?

Comment: Ummm hago ping a otra maquina, y desde la otra maquina a esta y me sirve, he leído que es un problema común en ubuntu 16.04, que se desconecta solo.  Pero no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: Puede ser que el servidor pase a bajo consumo y que al volver no se habilite todo correctamente. (en algunos equipos he tenido los mismos síntomas y al final era por la entrada y salida de bajo consumo)